# check document if there is mouse moving or touching like screensaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as the title says, i would like to know if theres any possibility in javascript (jquery) to check if there is any action in the document, and if not. something like a screensaver should pop up!
if someone is on the page and looks here, looks there and after a while he doesnt do anything, the mouse (or touch finger) stands still, i want to say the document after a minute without activity...

```
function noactivity() { //after 60000ms start something here }
```

i want that global for the whole document!
thanks ted

Answer (score 0):

It can be done relatively simply in jquery using:

```
setTimeout();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/hNkTy/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back while I was working on an iframe resizing issue. What I wanted was to tell the parent page whenever there is a change in height of the `document`.

What I found was that jQuery does not give such facility directly. The main reason for this is that there are too many activities happening to DOM which are not visible, when you are watching it (`bind`). You could however watch for a specific property like mouse moving on a document.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.pageY);
    console.log(e.pageX);
});
```

But then again that does not at all mean that the user is interacting with your page. That merely signifies that the user is on your page and his mouse is moving. The user might also be not moving the mouse and merely using his keyboard to interact with your page. So now you would have to watch for keyboard interaction aswell.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    console.log('active');
});
```

Using these you could create a countdown function which checks for a flag after a set interval of time. You could set the flag if user makes an activity. And after a set amount of time that function the 'noactivity()' function id the flag has not been set.

Another approach to watching the document activity could be you watching the DOM subtree being modified.

```
jQuery(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    console.log('active');
});
```

This works for Chrome/FireFox/IE8+ but not on Opera (any version). The main reason being that the operation is too heavy on your browser's resources. And I would discourage using this approach because listening for DOM mutation events may harm performance and the relevant W3C working groups are trying to find a better way to do this and deprecate DOM mutation events for this reason - it's hard or impossible to make a good and performant implementation.

I am not saying that the other options that I mentioned above are good either. They are also expensive operations if you are watching `document` and should be avoided. Another issue with those options is that the iframe content is not particularly the part of your `document` and these options will not work if user is interacting with iframe content.

So the conclusion is that W3C did not yet finalize a cheap way where user can watch changes in document subtree.